# all possible paths with directions and huge estimated rows! neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

we have some data about some nodes that nodes connected to each other with relations we called them ( cable )

the number of nodes is : 349 and the number of cables is : 924

we need to find possible path ( not shortest ) between two nodes and used this :

```
MATCH p=(n:location)-[*]-(m:location)
WHERE n.lo_id = 70 AND m.lo_id = 486
AND ALL(x IN NODES(p) WHERE SINGLE(y IN NODES(p) WHERE y = x))
return p
```

but it's failed . i used to explain and saw in plan that in "VarLengthExpand(Into)@neo4j" about

67,837,845,872,747,150,000 estimated rows !!!

what's wrong with this query ?

i'm newbie with neo4j . should i put index on fields or rewrite query ?

would you please help me to make it work and find possible path with a good query between nodes ?

Cypher version: CYPHER 4.4, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED.

Comment: You are basically looking for paths of any length in this query, which might be exponential in number? Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes. because i don't know how many nodes will be in path between this two node . user may select any start/end . it may contain 2 node between those selected or may over 100 nodes between those . i can't predict this number .

Comment: That is fine, but at the end do you want to know that there is a path between those nodes? Because as you can see there are billions of path between your two nodes, and that is not optimal in terms of query performance

Comment: Yes i wanted to know .i can set min/max if there is must

Comment: You just want to know if there is a path in between, not how many paths are there correct?

Comment: i don't know what do you want to find out . but i wanted to find out all possible paths between two nodes in neo4j . it may contains multiple node types but we just have 1 relation type ( cable ) .

Comment: I got it, in terms of optimization, I don't think we can do much, provided that your `WHERE` clause is as per the requirement. Your query currently is going through a major portion of the graph, and is not optimal

Comment: You can't do anything with your query condition, the amount of result is too huge, can cause OOM or slow down your app. There is not any apps doing this, they just find a shortest path, path with limit steps, range... or work with very small amount of node.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use APOC path expand config,

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-paths-config/

- set uniqueness to NODE_PATH
- use bfs: false
- use your end node as terminator node
- possible set a max depth at least as long as you're testing

What do you want to do with all those billions of paths?

Basically path expansion is degree to the power of hops.

So for graph with average degree of 10, a 10 hop path would be 10^10.

I would really suggest to first figure out what you want to do with all the paths and then express better how you want to guide the expansion.

If you have business rules, you can use the traversal API from a user defined procedure to guide the traversal/expansion at each step. (See the implementation of that APOC procedure on GitHub)